# Spring custom error message

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to set a custom error message via `@Controller`,
there is something like Struts `saveMessages(...)` in spring?

for example:

```
ActionErrors actionErrors = new ActionErrors();
actionErrors.add("error", new ActionMessage("error.missing.key",     
messageResources.getMessage("label.username"),  
messageResources.getMessage("label.password")));
saveErrors(request, actionErrors);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look at validation, Validators objects and so on:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator