# spring equivalent of ActionErrors

Tags: java, spring, validation

I am working on validation in Spring framework. I want to know the Spring equivalent of ActionErrors. I have gone though many materials which tells only about the Validator framework and the validate method which tells only about the form validation part. But my problem is, I have an exception caught, I have messages. I want to propagate these to jsp. Typically my Struts code peice is as below:

```
ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR,new ActionError("errors.msg",  messageResources.getMessage("label.username"), messageResources.getMessage("label.password")));
request.setAttribute(Globals.ERROR_KEY, errors);
```

In my jsp, I have  tag which takes care of displaying the error messages

How do I convert that to Spring?

I have already went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787517/spring-custom-error-message) post and have referred [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator) page as mentioned there. But all the links returns only Validator framework and the client side validaions using the validate() method. But what I am looking is how to propagate the error messages from my controller class to jsp view.

Comment: Check out `Errors` and `BindingResult`.